# Prompting for a URL to use while making a request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, httprequest

What I want to do is prompt a user to enter a url and with the url that is entered I want to make an http request. However I keep getting an error that says 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined."

When I hardcode the url straight into the request it works fine. It is only once I try to prompt it that I get an error.

```
var answer = '';
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("Enter a url you'd like to scrape: ", function(answer) {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log("This is the url you enetered:", answer);
  rl.close();
});

request(answer, function(error,response,html){
     //some code here
});
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to get things to execute asynchronously but they're working in an synchronous manner. This seems more along the lines of what you'd want to do:

```
'use strict';

const readline = require('readline');
const request = require('request');

let answer = '';

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("Enter a url you'd like to scrape: ", function(answer) {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log("This is the url you enetered:", answer);
  rl.close();
  crawl(answer, function (error, response, html) {
    console.log(html);
    // or whatever else you want
  });
});

//use wrapper function
function crawl(answer, callback){
  request(answer, function (error, response, html) {
    callback(error, response, html);
  });
}
```

You could also just use the `request(answer, function...)` call inside of `rl.question()`, but if you wrap it with another function you can get better readability and use it again elsewhere if you want

Comment: Thank you! As you said, wrapping it in another function worked perfectly. May I ask why you made readline, request and rl const?

Comment: Just a semantic thing — they never get modified, so const works best. var works just as well, but you just have the hoisting that'll happen. var hoisting isn't bad, but now that we have block scope in es6/2015 we can be clearer in what we want things to do :)